# ulimit command not found (without sudo) and error - coredumpsize: Can't set limit (Operation not permitted)

Tags: limit, csh, ulimit, core-dump

When i initially login to a server, I see the following error message.

```
ullimit: coredumpsize: Can't set limit (Operation not permitted)
```

Further, when I try to copy files into this machine, I see the same error,

```
cat .ssh/no_pass_rsa.pub | ssh user@server 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
user@server's password:
limit: coredumpsize: Can't set limit (Operation not permitted)
```

I read on a lot of blog posts that I must increase the hard limit and soft limit for the users. Trying the following command to check ulimit, gives the output as:

```
server> ulimit
ulimit: Command not found.
```

I could find no post where a user faced the issue of this operation not existing.

Also, I checked the limit and noticed that the coredumpsize is 0kbytes

```
$server> limit
cputime      unlimited
filesize     unlimited
datasize     unlimited
stacksize    33000 kbytes
coredumpsize 0 kbytes
memoryuse    unlimited
vmemoryuse   unlimited
descriptors  1048576
memorylocked 64 kbytes
maxproc      1030357
maxlocks     unlimited
maxsignal    1030357
maxmessage   819200
maxnice      0
maxrtprio    0
maxrttime    unlimited
```

How do I increase the coredump size or modify it to resolve this? Is there any other solution?

Comment: 1) What shell are you using? 2) Surely it's nothing called `ullimit` giving the error message, is it? 3) What are you actually trying to do? Save core dumps or something else?

Comment: On the server where you received this message `ulimit: Command not found`, `ulimit` executable is not in your search path or  someone deliberately deleted it. On the other end, where you get `Can't set limit (Operation not permitted)`, the userid executing `ulimit` command, doesn't have the privilege to change that setting. They are two different issues.

Comment: 1.Bash shell. 2. I am not sure what ullimit is. I thought I made a mistake and when I checked again the error actually contained the term "ullimit". Could not find any documentation regarding it as well. 3. I am trying to add myself as an authorized user on a server. So when I try to copy into this server, I face this issue. I have faced this before when I tried to copy files in and out of the server. Any idea as to what the issue  maybe?

Comment: @MelBurslan Thank you for the clarification. I realized that the 2 issues were due to completely different reasons and was able to fix them. I have posted the solution as well.

Comment: @MeghnaNatraj `ulimit` is a builtin command in Bash, so it's highly unlikely it would not be available on Bash. The `>` ending your prompt and the fact that `limit` works, but `ulimit` doesn't pretty much hints that you are actually running (t)csh instead of Bash. Your root shell might be Bash, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ulimit command not found - occurred as only the root user has the privileges to run this command and I was trying to execute it as a normal user. By running this as root, the command executed successfully.

Error Resolved - coredumpsize: Can't set limit (Operation not permitted)
The issue was resolved by editing the /etc/security/limits.conf and modifying the lines for setting core limits (as root user)

**File : /etc/security/limits.conf**

*Initially* :

```
# End of file
##### Begin HR 424923 ######
*        soft        nofile        8192
*        hard        nofile        8192
##### End HR 424923  ########

# Limit core dumps
*       soft    core    0
*       hard    core    0
```

*Finally* :

```
# End of file
##### Begin HR 424923 ######
*        soft        nofile        8192
*        hard        nofile        8192
##### End HR 424923  ########

# Limit core dumps
*       soft    core    65535
*       hard    core    65535
```

Answer (score 5):

`ulimit` is a `sh` family (so `bash`, `ksh` etc) builtin.  For `csh` family the command is `limit`.  (`zsh` is complicated and allows both.)

Normal users can *not* raise their hard limits.  Only `root` can do that.  On a typical Linux machine this is done via `pam_limits` (e.g. in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and files in `/etc/security/limits.d`).  These settings will take effect at login time (if using `sshd` then ensure `usePam yes` is set in `sshd_config`).

However users can *lower* their limits, so you might have a line in `.login` or `/etc/csh.login` or `/etc/profile.d/*` or similar that reduce the limit to zero, in which case that line will need removing.